# WSO2 Open Id Connect Single Logout

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, saml-2.0, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

How can I achieve single logout with openId connect with Identity Server 5.1.0
I see there is some documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+OpenID+Connect+Single+Logout) for this for version 5.2.0 but i can't open the link.

For logout in both applications right now, i'm following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29965502/525162
But now i want to logout the second application after the first one was logged off.

Do i really need SAML SSO?
Is this only possible for OpenId Connect from 5.2.0 forward?

Thanks,

Diogo

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is work in progress. That's why you can't access it right now. With 5.2.0 we have the OpenID Connect Session Management 1.0 spec[1] implemented which will allow you to do the use case you have mentioned.

ie. If there are two RP applications relying on WSO2 Identity Server, when an end user logs-out of one of the applications, he/she can be automatically logged out of the other one as well.

[1] http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

Comment: anyway I can do this right now or a patch for this use case i could apply?

Comment: you can try out 5.2.0-beta2 which has the required feature at https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/download/v5.2.0-beta2/wso2is-5.2.0-beta2.zip

Comment: I've just downloaded and ran it! but without documentation it's hard to understand where to search to implement this